# Alterar mensagem do último commit no GIT e push no GITHUB

Tags: github

Verificando o meu último push no github identifiquei kum erro de digitação na mensagem de commit, como alterar?

Comment: Você pode ver essa informação no link abaixo: https://docs.github.com/pt/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alterando o último commit no repositório Git...**
1-Na linha de comando, navegue até o repositório que contém o commit que você deseja corrigir.

2-Digite git commit --amend e pressione Enter.

3-No editor de texto, edite a mensagem do commit e salve o commit.

**Enviando para o Github o commit alterado**

Agora Use o comando push --force para forçar o push sobre o commit antigo.
git push --force

Pronto... espero ter ajudado...
Na fonte você vai achar mais detalhes e alternativas ok!
Fonte: https://docs.github.com/pt/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/changing-a-commit-message

Comment: Legal, resolveu meu problema! Grato!